# SwiftUI Nested NavigationLink in VStack not opening new page

Tags: swift, swiftui, ios16

*Hello everyone, I recently got a Mac and I am making my first app in Swift so bear with me.*

While making a library app I have encountered issues with the navigation link that is nested inside of a vstack. When clicking on the navigation link, instead of opening a new 'page' it only opens inside of the vstack. Is it an issue with the placement of the navigation view? If so, how do I correct this? Below is my code and some screenshots I took that better explain the issue.

```
 ScrollView(.vertical, showsIndicators: false){
                VStack{
                    NavigationView {
                        VStack(alignment: .leading){
                            Text("Poetry")
                                .font(.largeTitle)
                                .foregroundColor(Color("lightCyan"))
                                .fontWeight(.heavy)
                                .padding(.leading)
                            ScrollView(.horizontal, showsIndicators: false)
                            {
                                HStack(spacing: 25){
                                    NavigationLink(destination: pageOne()) {
                                        VStack(spacing: 15) {
                                            Image("paulDunbar")
                                                .resizable()
                                                .frame(width: imageWidthSize, height: imageHeightSize)
                                                .cornerRadius(10)
                                            
                                            Divider()
                                                .frame(width: imageWidthSize - 50, height: 2)
                                                .overlay(.white)
                                            Text("The Path")
                                                .fontWeight(.bold)
                                                .multilineTextAlignment(.center)
                                                .foregroundColor(Color("lightCyan"))
                                                .font(.headline)
                                            
                                            Text("Paul Laurence Dunbar")
                                                .multilineTextAlignment(.center)
                                                .foregroundColor(Color("lightCyan"))
                                                .font(.subheadline)
                                                .italic()
                                            
                                        }}
                                    .padding(.all)
                                    .background(Color("dazzledBlue"))
                                    //.border(.black, width: 0)
                                    .cornerRadius(10)
                                    
                                    .buttonStyle(PlainButtonStyle())
```

[image][image]

I have tried removing the Vstack but this does not work as the formatting goes away. I have also tried adding a button inside of the vstack for the user to click but the same issue still happens.

Comment: Some observations: is this really the code that gives you your issues? It seems to me that you have some 
ScrollViews, but no `ForEach{..}` to to go with it. Have you tried moving `NavigationView`, 
completely outside the ScrollView, wrapping everything?